# Using LDAP plugin in Plone: is it safe to substitute: cn attribute with: displayName, mapped to: fullname?

Tags: plone, openldap, plone-4.x

I'm using Active Directory as authentication source in a Plone4 site, with plone.app.ldap.

In the settings I'm using *sAMAccountName* for user id, but the *cn* attribute does not contain user fullname information, which instead is provided by the attribute: *displayName*

To display the correct fullname, in ZMI > ldap-plugin > LDAP Schema, I've deleted *cn* attribute, and added: *displayName*, mapped to: *fullname*. Now everything seems to be working fine in my test enviroment: just wondering if this is the correct pratice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a safe procedure and it is a good place to change your configuration